# Google Speech API: **Monthly usage is capped at 1 million minutes per month

Tags: google-cloud-speech

There is a monthly usage cap at 1 million minutes per month. Does that mean if my users (*of my project/app which is using this api*) avg. usage is 60 minutes/1 hour per day => 1440 minutes per month, then I can have maximum ~700 (*1000,000/1440*) users for my apps? If this is right, then my user base can never grow beyond 700 right?

Is my calculation right? or I misread something in the document:

https://cloud.google.com/speech/

Answer (score 1):

In the doc there  is 
Processing per day  480 hours of audio
"These limits apply to each Cloud Speech API developer project, and are shared across all applications and IP addresses using a given a developer project."
So you might have a problem here.

Does all your use every day 1 hour ?
If yes, you still have the possibility to send a Quota request as written in this page : https://cloud.google.com/speech/pricing

Good luck